# Using the MySQL command line, how can I display only date or amount (Decimal) columns in a Select statement?

Tags: mysql, select, sqldatatypes

I am new to SQL and I realize I have a lot to learn. I am in the midst of converting a set of ISAM files into MySQL tables. Some of the tables I am creating have hundreds of columns. To make it easier to see if my conversions are working properly, I would like to display only a subset of columns at a time in my SELECT results.

For example, I would like to see only Dates or only Amounts (i.e., Decimals). This would make it easier to see if correct values are in those fields.

I am working from the MySQL command line and I would rather not specify a long list of column names if it can be avoided. Is there a way to get my Select statements to display only the types of columns I am interested in?

---

(Added 5/12/16) 
I used a variant of Uueerdo's syntax to create a view:

create view dates_view as concat('select ', group_concat(column_name), ' ',' from ', table_schema, '.', table_name, ';') from information_schema.columns where table_name = 'binders_tbl' and data_type in ('date');

When I enter select * from dates_view; I get this value:

select binder_effectiveDate,binder_expirationDate,binder_submissionCreatedDate,binder_f‌​irstQuotedDate,binder_boundDate,binder_invoicedDate,binder_terminatedDate,binder_‌​cancelledDate from aesdb.binders_tbl;

I tried but could not find a way to use this view with "select * from binders_tbl;" to display only the above date fields and their values.

If anyone can guide me to a "join" or "subquery" solution, I would appreciate it. For now, I am going to stick with listing all the individual columns as needed. Plus, I will study more basic and intermediate SQL. Thank you to those who responded.

---

(Added 5/20/16)
**I found a sort-of work-around to my problem**. Here it is in case it helps someone else:

**CREATE VIEW DateCols_View AS SELECT Table1_SelectionCriteriaField, Table1_Date1, Table1_Date2, Table1_Date3 FROM Table1;**

**SELECT * FROM DateCols_View WHERE Table1_SelectionCriteriaField (matches some criteria);**

My work-around has **2 drawbacks**. **The first** is that I have to include any selection criteria fields that I plan to use later. But with a little forethought I can create multiple views with different sets of columns for different displays. This will let me display only those columns I wish to see while working with a set of records. I plan to create separate views for Dates, Amounts, Flags, etc.

**The other drawback** is that I have to create a separate set of views for each table or join combination I plan to work with.

I hope as I learn more about SQL, I will find a way to generalize this technique (to make it more like a script or macro) and simplify it further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, you have to specify column names. There is no syntax for dynamic field inclusion, however you could maybe work something out with information_schema (like below) to generate a query for you to use.

```
SELECT CONCAT('SELECT ', GROUP_CONCAT(column_name), ' '
,'FROM `', table_schema, '`.`', table_name, '`;'
FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE table_schema = 'yourschemaname' 
AND table_name = 'yourtablename' 
AND data_type IN ('timestamp', 'date'[, etc....])
;
```

Comment: "new to SQL" and "dynamic SQL" probably don't mix well. :)

Comment: I used a variant of Uueerdo's syntax to create a view:</br></br>create view dates_view as concat('select ', group_concat(column_name), ' ',' from ', table_schema, '.', table_name, ';') from information_schema.columns where table_name = 'binders_tbl' and data_type in ('date');<\br><\br>When I enter select * from dates_view; I get this value:<\br><\br>select binder_effectiveDate,binder_expirationDate,binder_submissionCreatedDate,binder_firstQuotedDate,binder_boundDate,binder_invoicedDate,binder_terminatedDate,binder_cancelledDate  from aesdb.binders_tbl;<\br><\br>. (Continued in next comment.)

Comment: @Barmar true, but short of manually typing out a potentially VERY long query, this is the only automatic way (other than some sort of query building tool); and you can't really hurt much with a select on the information schema.

Comment: @StevenShatz Oh, a word of caution, if you have ALOT of field names in the final query, you may want to check your server's group_concat_max_len(http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len) to make sure the full field list is not being truncated.

Comment: Sorry, I am having trouble entering blank lines and editing my comments. Everything's a learning curve.<br\>How can I join the results of my view with a select * from binders_tbl;?

Comment: @StevenShatz it is usually best in my perception to append such things to your original question using a separator to denote the update. Also, I have not used VIEWs a whole lot so my info level there is kinda low; and that query I provided (and view you wrapped it with) does not return data, it returns a query string you can use to retrieve the data.

Comment: @StevenShatz The reason you're having trouble is because formatting isn't allowed in comments.

Comment: @Uueerdo and Barmar Thank you both for your help with SQL and StackOverflow. I will look into how I can use the query string to reduce my result set from what is currently 100 fields to 8 (for dates) and 12 (for dollar amounts). I can always just list the full subset, so I have a workaround. I also realize I am jumping the gun with this attempt and I need to learn more basics first.